# Error Connecting Frontend and Backend on Different Ports with Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, cors, port

**Description:**

I've been working on a project that involves a frontend and a backend component, both running on different ports. However, I'm encountering an error when trying to connect them. Specifically, I'm receiving the following error message in my browser's developer console when I input a message for my chatbot:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I've tried to resolve this issue by importing flask_cors, but I'm getting the error:

```
Import "flask_cors" could not be resolved from source
```

Here's a snippet of my frontend (app.js):

```
class Chatbox {
  constructor() {
    this.args = {
      openButton: document.querySelector(".chatbox__button"),
      sendButton: document.querySelector(".send__button"),
    };

    this.state = false;
    this.messages = [];
  }

  toggleState(chatBox) {
    chatBox.classList.toggle("chatbox--active");
  }

  onSendButton(chatBox) {
    var textField = chatBox.querySelector("input");
    let text1 = textField.value;
    if (text1 === "") {
      return;
    }

    let msg1 = { name: "User", message: text1 };
    this.messages.push(msg1);

    fetch($SCRIPT_ROOT + "predict", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: text1 }),
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((r) => {
        let msg2 = { name: "Sam", message: r.answer };
        this.messages.push(msg2);
        this.updateChatText(chatBox);
        textField.value = "";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        this.updateChatText(chatBox);
        textField.value = "";
      });
  }

  updateChatText(chatBox) {
    var html = "";
    this.messages
      .slice()
      .reverse()
      .forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (item.name === "Sam") {
          html +=
            '<div class="messages__item messages__item--visitor">' +
            item.message +
            "</div>";
        } else {
          html +=
            '<div class="messages__item messages__item--operator">' +
            item.message +
            "</div>";
        }
      });

    const chatMessage = chatBox.querySelector(".chatbox__messages");
    chatMessage.innerHTML = html;
  }

  display() {
    const { openButton, sendButton } = this.args;
    const chatBox = document.querySelector(".chatbox__support");

    openButton.addEventListener("click", () => this.toggleState(chatBox));

    sendButton.addEventListener("click", () => this.onSendButton(chatBox));

    const inputNode = chatBox.querySelector("input");
    inputNode.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        this.onSendButton(chatBox);
      }
    });
  }
}

const chatbox = new Chatbox();
chatbox.display();
```

And here's a snippet of my backend (app.py):

```
import sys
print("Python Interpreter Path:", sys.executable)

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from chat import get_response
from flask_cors import CORS  # Import CORS from flask_cors

app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure CORS for the entire app
CORS(app)

@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def index_get():
    return render_template("base.html")

@app.route("/predict", methods=['POST'])
def predict():
    text = request.get_json().get("message")
    # TO-DO: check if text is valid
    response = get_response(text)
    message = {"answer": response}
    return jsonify(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=3000)
```

Can anyone help me identify what's causing the "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error and how to properly set up CORS in my Flask app?

Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` indicates that the error is not related to CORS.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a problem with CORS. Your back-end lives at `http://localhost:3000` and I assume `SCRIPT_ROOT`  does not specify the back-end's address. (For example, if you fetch `/api/something`, the browser will send the request to `http://[The page's route]/api/something`. Try using a reverse proxy.